# One to many polymorphic relationship

Tags: eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5.4, relationship

It's a common situation but I somehow couldn't manage to find a reasonable solution so far. Basically I need the following:
I have the model `House` which contains a couple of other models (e.g. `Brick`, 'Stick', 'Chair' etc.). Each one of them has a belongsTo relation to the House (so basically in the `sticks`, `chairs` and `bricks` table there is a `house_id` column). Each model contains a `public function house()` method which returns the house they're part of. Now comes the problem that I'd like to get all of a house's supplies by a method, let's say for example `public function supplies()`, which should return a collection of instances of the classes `Stick`, `Chair` and `Brick`. Is there any convenient way to achieve that? Could I for example unite those classes by a trait and somehow point to that trait in the house's method or maybe with a BaseClass, let's say `Supply`, that all the supplies should inherit? Any recommendances? Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for this in Laravel.

You can define separate `HasMany` relationships and then merge them with an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```php
class House extends Model {
    public function bricks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Brick::class);
    }

    public function chairs() {
        return $this->hasMany(Chair::class);
    }

    public function sticks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Stick::class);
    }

    public function getSuppliesAttribute() {
        return $this->bricks->toBase()->merge($this->chairs)->merge($this->sticks);
    }
}

$supplies = $house->supplies;
```

+++ UPDATE +++

I've created a package for merging relationships using views:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-merged-relations

First, create the merge view in a migration:

```php
use Staudenmeir\LaravelMergedRelations\Facades\Schema;

Schema::createMergeView(
    'supplies', [(new House)->bricks(), (new House)->chairs(), (new House)->sticks()]
);
```

Then define the relationship:

```php
class House extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\LaravelMergedRelations\Eloquent\HasMergedRelationships;

    public function supplies()
    {
        return $this->mergedRelation('supplies');
    }
}
```

Use it like any other relationship:

```php
House::find($id)->supplies;

House::find($id)->supplies()->paginate();

House::with('supplies')->get();
```

Comment: I thought of the exact same solution, the only problem being one little circumstance I've encountered throughout my experience. Interfering with the database via an accessor has brought me severe problems with errors when creating new instances of the class that are not connected to the database or don't even exist as entries there and it was some severe problem on vendor level. Are you sure this would be a safe approach here? Alternatively, I can initialize a method for the purpose, but then I'd lose any kind of relationship functionality. Any thoughts?

Comment: The accessor approach can only be used to retrieve data. If you need the full relationship support, you'll probably have to write your own relationship type.

Comment: Yes, thought of that as well... I'll go on with trying this approach out, but still I have some doubts about the work with relations in an accessor, because as already mentioned, I've previously been encountering a flood of `trying to get property of null` errors when using them with non database bound instances of the class. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Non database bound instances of the `House` class?

Comment: Yes. Earlier I had similar problems with such models - Laravel was somehow trying to register the accessor initiated attribute as a default attribute of the model instance and was throwing errors all over the place, because all database relations were returning `null`... which also makes sense

Comment: I've created a package for merging relationships and added it to my answer.

Comment: I'd love to check your package out! I think this should be added to upcoming versions of laravel! Btw, I'm coming to study Informatics at TUM this winter :P